# Why does psycopg2 "SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom)" return "<read-only buffer...>"?

Tags: arcpy, postgis, well-known-binary, psycopg2

I'm trying to retrieve polygons out of a postgresql database and I'm running into several problems. First, I've been able to get `ST_AsText(geom)` to work in conjunction with `arcpy.FromWKT()`, but the precision is lost as described in the [PostGIS docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html):

> WKT format does not maintain precision so to prevent floating truncation, use ST_AsBinary or ST_AsEWKB format for transport.

But when I try to use `ST_AsBinary` or `ST_AsEWKB` with `arcpy.FromWKB` I get these errors:

```
cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom) FROM master.modeled_yield_hotspots WHERE model_id = 4;")
lsTemp = cur.fetchall()
lsGeom = []
for j in range(0, len(lsTemp)):
    lsGeom.append(arcpy.FromWKB(lsTemp[j]))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lsGeom, pathScratchGDB + "fcHotspots")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SmartFarm_Tools\python_scripts\testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    lsGeom.append(arcpy.FromWKB(lsTemp[j]))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1640, in FromWKB
    return gp.createObject("geometry", byte_array, None, spatial_reference)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 379, in createObject
    self._gp.CreateObject(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot create geometry from inputs
```

If I print `lsTemp[j]` I get the following:

```
(<read-only buffer for 0x0000000012808190, size 82146, offset 0 at 0x0000000003092F10>,)
```

What is a `read-only buffer`? How do I get WKB out of postgis and into a feature class or shapefile?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422685/1394393) for information about what buffers are.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [from the documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/fromwkb.htm) that `arcpy.FromWKB` expects a `bytearray` data type, which you can get using the [`bytearray()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom)
    FROM master.modeled_yield_hotspots
    WHERE model_id = %s;
""", (4,))
lsGeom = []
for r in cur:
    lsGeom.append(arcpy.FromWKB(bytearray(r[0])))
```

Comment: Did this. Still got an error. =/ And I'm certain the conversion worked correctly. (I can do a direct hexadecimal comparison between the source and the `bytearray`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're already interfacing with your data in PostGIS using ArcPy, you could simply use a SearchCursor, manipulate the data as needed, and then insert it into a shapefile/fGDB feature class using an InsertCursor.

You don't need to use Psycopg2 to pull the data out, the SearchCursor can handle that.